# Append first item to end of iterable in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I need to append the first item of a (general) iterable as the final item of that iterable (thus "closing the loop"). I've come up with the following:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
from itertools import chain

def close_loop(iterable: Iterable) -> Iterable:
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    first = next(iterator)
    return chain([first], iterator, [first])

# Examples:
list(close_loop(range(5)))  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
''.join(close_loop('abc'))  # 'abca'
```

Which works, but seems a bit "clumsy". I was wondering if there's a more straightforward approach using the magic of `itertools`. Solutions using `more_itertools` are also highly welcome.

Comment: you only need to modify the final line of your `close_loop` code, `return [first, *iterator, first]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a version which doesn't use `itertools`

```py
def close_loop(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    first = next(iterator)
    yield first
    yield from iterator
    yield first
```

Comment: Nice. There's an elegance to simple and direct.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.tee`:

```
from itertools import chain, tee

def close_loop(iterable):
    orig, dupl = tee(iterable, 2)
    first = next(orig)
    return chain(dupl,[first])
```